# Background image in a scrollable relativeLayout

Tags: android, xml

Please give me a hint on how I can make this picture occupy the entire screen no matter the orientation or the size of the screen.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"

    tools:context="com.gadgetcatch.alex.cardcelebration.MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/background" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The pictures above are on Nexus4 and Nexus 10 with no atributes. On the nexus 10 the picture is not even in the main image, it starts after.
[image: Nexus4]
[image: Nexus10]

Adding adjustViewBounds="true" does make the picture as wide as the screen but still leaves a blank strip at the bottom on Nexus 10 devices

[image: picture with adjustView]

What atribute must be used so that the picture will occupy the whole screen no matter the device used. Thanks in advance to anyone who can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the relative layout occupies the whole screen, you will always get that white strip at the bottom, because the match parent attribute on the image view.

This is what I would do:

- Use a FrameLayout as the root layout, with match_parent width and height.
- Add the ImageView as a child, with match_parent width and height and android:scaleType="centerCrop".
- Add the ScrollView as a FrameLayout child.

So, the structure will look like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.gadgetcatch.alex.cardcelebration.MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/background"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

I forgot to add, using this approach the image won't scroll, it will always cover the whole screen.

Comment: Your answer is good as it solves the problem I have. It is not exactly what I wanted but it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:scaleType="centerCrop" android:adjustViewBounds="true"` the image will fill up the whole screen no matter what, but the sides may be cropped out.

Comment: This is what I am trying to say here. That using centerCrop and adjustViewBounds does not fill the whole screen. It still leaves a white strip at the bottom when I transfer this to a device

Comment: Add android:fillViewport="true" to ScrollView

Comment: Nope, still not working. I am sure that it's something stupid that I just don't see...